# How to fix system upgrade failure?

Tags: 18.04, package-management, upgrade, samba, services

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libmpcdec6 libplacebo4 libva-wayland2 libwine-development
  libwine-development:i386 wine-stable wine-stable-amd64 wine-stable-i386:i386
  wine32-development:i386 wine64-development
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up winbind (2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.5) ...
Job for winbind.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status winbind.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript winbind, action "restart" failed.
● winbind.service - Samba Winbind Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/winbind.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-12-02 15:59:26 +06; 10ms ago
     Docs: man:winbindd(8)
           man:samba(7)
           man:smb.conf(5)
  Process: 13298 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/winbindd --foreground --no-process-group $WINBINDOPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 13298 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

ডিসেম্বর 02 15:59:25 rubel systemd[1]: Starting Samba Winbind Daemon...
ডিসেম্বর 02 15:59:26 rubel winbindd[13298]: invalid permissions on directory '/var/log/samba/cores': has 0777 should be 0700
ডিসেম্বর 02 15:59:26 rubel winbindd[13298]: Failed to create /var/log/samba/cores for user 0 with mode 0700
ডিসেম্বর 02 15:59:26 rubel winbindd[13298]: Unable to setup corepath for winbindd: No such file or directory
ডিসেম্বর 02 15:59:26 rubel winbindd[13298]: invalid permissions on directory '/var/log/samba/cores': has 0777 should be 0700
ডিসেম্বর 02 15:59:26 rubel winbindd[13298]: Failed to create /var/log/samba/cores for user 0 with mode 0700
ডিসেম্বর 02 15:59:26 rubel winbindd[13298]: Unable to setup corepath for winbindd: No such file or directory
ডিসেম্বর 02 15:59:26 rubel systemd[1]: winbind.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
ডিসেম্বর 02 15:59:26 rubel systemd[1]: winbind.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
ডিসেম্বর 02 15:59:26 rubel systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba Winbind Daemon.
dpkg: error processing package winbind (--configure):
 installed winbind package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up samba (2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.5) ...
Samba is not being run as an AD Domain Controller.
Please ignore the following error about deb-systemd-helper not finding samba-ad-dc.service.
Job for smbd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status smbd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript smbd, action "start" failed.
● smbd.service - Samba SMB Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/smbd.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-12-02 15:59:30 +06; 9ms ago
     Docs: man:smbd(8)
           man:samba(7)
           man:smb.conf(5)
  Process: 13391 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group $SMBDOPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 13391 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

ডিসেম্বর 02 15:59:30 rubel systemd[1]: Starting Samba SMB Daemon...
ডিসেম্বর 02 15:59:30 rubel systemd[1]: smbd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
ডিসেম্বর 02 15:59:30 rubel systemd[1]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
ডিসেম্বর 02 15:59:30 rubel systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba SMB Daemon.
dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure):
 installed samba package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 winbind
 samba
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please do not revert trivial changes like code formatting. Please [edit] and add the output of `systemctl status winbind.service` and `systemctl status smbd.service`, each in a code block (`{}` button). What does (re)starting these services with e.g. `systemctl restart winbind.service` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system upgrade failed due to permission bug with windbind package. 
You need to fixed permission by following command and restart windbind service.

```
sudo chmod 0700 /var/log/samba/cores
sudo systemctl restart winbind.service
```

After that you should be able to complete system upgrade.